# In Hibernate how do you filter if an element is in a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, filter

I have an entity that contains a list of strings member. How do I put a filter to check if the list of strings contains a certain string? I tried putting hql equivalent of "in elements" in the condition clause but that didn't work.

```
@Filter(name="exampleFilter", condition ="'element' in elements(collectionList) ")
```

Comment: Please show your hql. Which hibernate version are you using?